# Pocketing the last coin and the striker at the same time

Tags: carrom

1. Only one black (mine) and one white (opponent's) coin are on the board. (All the other coins and the queen have been pocketed)
2. I pocket my black coin, but accidentally also pocket the striker.

Who will win?

Comment: Have you already covered the Queen, or are you trying to cover the Queen with this shot?

Comment: I have already covered queen.

Answer (score 2):

**Nobody wins yet.** You return 2 C/m to the board and continue your turn. According to [the ICF rules](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm):

> 70. If a player pockets the Striker with his own C/m by a proper stroke, the number of C/m so pocketed, with a Due C/m, shall be taken out for placing and the player shall continue his turn.

Answer (score 0):

If we put the opponent's last coin without finishing red then we are lost. If we put our last coin without finishing red then we have to place one minus.